# Order of the 0 of this function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the order of the root z=0 of $z(1-(\cos(z))^2)$

Now i have expanded it around z=0, let's say that $$z(1-(\cos(z))^2) = z^3 +O(z^5)$$

Now, at $z=0$, $\frac{d^2(z^3 +O(z^5))}{dz^2} = \frac{d(z^3 +O(z^5))}{dz} = z^3 +O(z^5) = 0$, but $\frac{d^3(z^3 +O(z^5))}{dz^3}|_{z=0} \neq 0$ , so that the order of 0 is 3.

But the answer is 5, where is my error?

Comment: $(1-\cos z)^2=4\sin^4{z/2}$ etc

Comment: You are correct that $z(1-\cos^2z)$ has a zero of order $3$; @Conrad is correct that $z(1-\cos z)^2$ has a zero of order $5$. Perhaps there's a typo or a misreading of the problem?

Comment: Could it be that you confused $1-(\cos z)^2$ and $(1-\cos z)^2$ when reading the problem?